# comparing different columns of different data frames and flag matching

Tags: r

I have two data frames as below as below

```
df1<- 
 data.frame("name"=c("tom","bob","owen","john"),"last_name"=c("trump","obama"),"age"=c(24,28),"number"=c(1,2))
```

```
df2<-data.frame("name"=c("bob","owen","tom","marry"),"age"=c(28,26),"number"=c(3,1))
```

I want to compare some specific columns between two data frames and create a status column in df1 if they match it should flag match and not match it should flag not match as below:

````
df1 <- data.frame("name"=c("tom","bob","owen","john"),"last_name"=c("trump","obama"),"age"=c(24,28),"number"=c(1,2),"name_status"=c("matched","matched","matched","not matched"),"age_status"=c("notmatched","matched","not matched","matched"), "number_status"=c("matched","notmatched"))
    ```
    I tried using which %in% but as number of match is less than number of rows it throws an error
    Thank you for helping in advance
````

Comment: @Ronak Shah I want to create a new column in df1 like name_status and flag match and not matched values of name column in df1 and df2

Comment: Will you always have same number of rows for `df1` and `df2` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah no different number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
df1$name_status = ifelse(df1$name %in% df2$name, 'matched', 'not matched')
```

For multiple columns:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(1:length(names(df2)), function(i) ifelse(df1[, names(df2)[i]] %in% df2[, i], 'matched', 'not matched'))) -> df3
colnames(df3) <- paste0(names(df2), '_status')
df1 <- cbind(df1, df3)
```

Comment: Thank you what if I compare like 50 column? if I use ifelse for each it is time consuming to write for each variable this code is there any way to do it for some specific columns like above I checked name,age and number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` :

```
cols <- paste0(names(df2), '_status')
df1[cols] <- Map(`%in%`, df1[names(df2)], df2)
df1

#  name last_name age number name_status age_status number_status
#1  tom     trump  24      1        TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
#2  bob     obama  28      2        TRUE       TRUE         FALSE
#3 owen     trump  24      1        TRUE      FALSE          TRUE
#4 john     obama  28      2       FALSE       TRUE         FALSE
```

If you want output as `'Matched'`, `'Not matched'`

```
df1[cols] <- c('Not matched', 'Matched')[as.matrix(df1[cols] + 1)]
df1

#  name last_name age number name_status  age_status number_status
#1  tom     trump  24      1     Matched Not matched       Matched
#2  bob     obama  28      2     Matched     Matched   Not matched
#3 owen     trump  24      1     Matched Not matched       Matched
#4 john     obama  28      2 Not matched     Matched   Not matched
```